# Overwriting typography styling

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with the styling of typography on a website that I'm creating.

I've stated a color for the `P` element so that It's consistent with the website, however, I need to make a certain section of text white because of the backgrounds grey. I tried to use a tag on the text and give it an important tag so it'd turn white, but it didn't work for me.

```css
p {
color: #3c3c3b;
}
```

I then created this class and added it to the `P` element to try and turn it white.

```css
.white {
color: #fff!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by using an `ID` rather than a class, this code overwrote the class.

```css
#white {
  color: #fff
}
```